# Передача программой VBS параметров при запуске другой программе

Tags: windows, vbscript

Необходимо, дабы программа на VBS передавала параметры при запуске другой программе. Для запуска стороннего приложения я использую объект WScript.Shell вкупе с методом Run. Не хватает того, чтобы скрипт передавал вызываемой программе при запуске ещё и параметры. Попросту, мне неизвестен синтаксис, с помощью коего это можно осуществить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нагло стырено из https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087470/run-command-line-command-from-vbs

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oshell.run "notepad.exe I_will_always_google_before_ask"
```